# remove scoped/inline styles from head, Vue JS

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-component, inline-styles

I've pulled in [this Vue music player](https://github.com/SevenOutman/vue-aplayer) component, and I would like to know if its possible to remove the styles it adds to the `<head/>` of my doc and move them to a singular `css` file.

**Here is the importation of the component in one of my components:**

```
import Aplayer from 'vue-aplayer'

export default {
  components: {
    Aplayer
  }
}
```

**Here's a shot of what it injects into my** `<head/>` :

[image]

As you can see, thats a ton of un-cached styling. How do I take the scoped styles of a remote package and output them to a proprietary `css` file using `Webpack` or native `Vue` capabilities?

Comment: The CSS is added by the bundled Javascript. The Javascript is cached. Aint it enough?

Comment: the javascript maybe cached however the injected styles are never cached... and I'd just prefer to have them in a separate file rather than the head @JacobGoh

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I'm having an issue where the inline styles/scripts in head are being blocked by my CSP